# Content disposition is not working with SAS + CDN in azure

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I have a question. I need to download a file from azure blob storage CDN by signed url and loaded file must have custom name. I've found that I can use "Corresponding SAS query parameters" to do it. The thing is that it works only if I use signed url (sas) direct to blob container for instance

```
https://test.blob.core.windows.net/data/images/111-111-111-11?sig=<sig>&se=2018-04-18T22%3A32%3A27Z&sv=2017-07-29&rscd=attachment%3Bfilename%3Dtsv.jpg&sp=rwdl&sr=b
```

in this case downloaded file has name **tsv.jpg**

but it doesn't go if I generate sas and use it for CDN

```
https://test.azureedge.net/images/111-111-111-11?sig=<sig>&se=2018-04-18T22%3A34%3A26Z&sv=2017-07-29&rscd=attachment%3Bfilename%3Dtsv.jpg&sp=rwdl&sr=b
```

but in this case downloaded file has name **111-111-111-11**

Comment: Can't reproduce it on my side. I notice the second url is using `/images` instead of `/data/images`, is there anything different between your test data location or have you done any other settings on your cdn?

Comment: Yes. I have a container with name _data_ and CDN has setting which allow to have an access direct to _data_ container.

Comment: Did my solution work or you need further help? If it did help, it will be appreciated if you could accept it as an answer for more people to refer.

Comment: Sorry for delay with response. I couldn't check your solution yet. When I have results I'll definitely leave feedback here

Answer (score 0):

Find one solution for you to refer.

It turns out related to features of CDN. As you know CDN caches content on edge servers, after the first request to CDN endpoint, the content is cached and won't be updated unless its TTL expires.

So you may have cached file named `111-111-111-11` in edge server, plus the default `query string cache behavior` is `ignore query strings`, which means it ignores the query string in url if the content `111-111-111-11` has been cached.

You can change the `query string cache behavior` settings to `Cache every unique URL` or `Bypass caching for query strings`.

You can find the settings in CDN endpoint panel. You can follow [Azure document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-query-string#changing-query-string-caching-settings-for-standard-cdn-profiles).
[image]

Or if you are using Premium tier CDN profile, similar settings to `Query-String Caching`. Feel free to ask if you have further questions.